# How to get MSER component tree via opencv

Tags: opencv, mser

I am using opencv now. I found MSER only provide the `operator()` function which return `vector<vector<Point> >`, How could I get the component tree structure of MSER region?

Comment: the opencv API won't allow it.

Comment: So I have to implement MSER tree generation algorithm by myself?

Answer (score 1):

I found I could use the following API void ERFilter::run(InputArray image, std::vector& regions) provied by opencv 3.0 alpha to get component tree